# Can a 64 GB memory card be used in a Nikon D80?

Tags: dslr, memory-card, sdcard, nikon-d80

I am attempting to format a 64 GB SD memory card for an upcoming trip. Using the instructions provided by Nikon, I receive a flashing "FULL" and 0 frames/pictures after formatting.

What can I do to format this card?

Comment: Related: [what is the highest capacity sdhc card I can use in my Nikon D 40 camera?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/76277)

Comment: Related: [Can a firmware upgrade enable a camera to use SDXC memory cards?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/69939)

Comment: Related: [Can a firmware upgrade enable a Nikon D90 to use SDXC memory cards?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/81956)

Answer (score 4):

The card appears to be too big. From [Nikon's Support Site](https://www.nikonimgsupport.com/ni/NI_article?articleNo=000002140&configured=1&lang=en_US):

> Approved SD cards for D80
>
> The following SD memory cards have been approved for use in the D80 digital SLR. All cards of the designated make and capacity can be used, regardless of speed.
>
> Nikon 512MB, 1GB
>   SanDisk 64MB, 128MB, 256MB, 512MB, 1GB, 2GB1*, 4GB2*
>   Panasonic 64MB, 128MB, 256MB, 512MB, 1GB, 2GB1*, 4GB2*
>   Toshiba 64MB, 128MB, 256MB, 512MB, 1GB, 2GB1*
>
> All SD memory cards indicated above can be used regardless of their transfer speed.
>
> Lexar Media
>   256 MB, 512 MB, 1 GB
>   Platinum II (60x) series: 512 MB, 1 GB
>   Professional (133x) series: 1 GB, 2 GB1
>
> 1* If the memory card will be used with a card reader or other device, the device must support 2-GB SD memory cards.
>   2* SDHC-compliant.

I don't have direct experience with Nikon but can say that Canon cameras in the past have required firmware updates to use newer cards. In addition to obtaining a smaller card, you may still need to do a firmware update.

Answer (score 2):

There are different types of [SD cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital): SD/SDSC, SDHC, SDXC, SDUC. Your camera is compatible with SD/SDSC and SDHC cards that are 4GB or smaller. See the [Nikon D80 user manual](https://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/products/8/D80.html) for details (page 122).

A [firmware update](https://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/download/fw/8.html) *may* add support for larger cards, as well as fix other issues. However, all SDHC cards are 32GB or smaller, so your 64GB card would likely still not work.

Answer (score 2):

My solution to this problem was to format the 64gb card in the camera which produced a non-working card giving the Full error. I then put the card in my laptop and using Aomei partition manger reduced the partition size to below 32gb. The card then worked perfectly in the camera. Though obviously half capacity. If you reformat the card in the camera it will revert to 64gb and stop working.

Answer (score 0):

SDXC cards are required to fall back to slower access modes, so from an electrical perspective, it is compatible.

However, older cameras don't support the exFAT filesystem that is typically used for volumes with more than 32 GB of data on the card.  To work around that, you will likely have to repartition the card with a single 32 GB partition, and then format that partition as FAT32.  It is not possible to do this with the camera itself.  You would have to do this with a flash reader attached to a computer.

And note that the result will effectively act like a 32 GB flash card, not a 64 GB card.  So although you can do this in a pinch, you probably should just buy 32 GB SDHC cards and save a few bucks per card.

Then again, from a wear-leveling perspective, a 64 GB flash card that only gets halfway used will last twice as long as a 32 GB flash card, if all else is equal, so ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.

It *may* be possible to reformat it as a 64 GB FAT32 volume, but only if the camera's firmware supports working with FAT32 volumes that have a 16 KB cluster size.  And the resulting volume may or may not work on Windows.

Comment: This answer is inaccurate.  [FAT32](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table) *does* support partition sizes larger than 32GB (apparently up to 16TB).

Comment: _conventional wisdom_ (to the extent that's valuable) generally recommends letting the camera format the card. Personally, I can't recall personally ever having issues with PC-formatted SD(XC/HC) cards in my cameras, but I tend to let my cameras format the cards. Although, the SDCard Association recommends the only _officially_ recommended way is to use the [formatter software provided the SDCard Association](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/) itself to format the card. So there's that... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  =)

Comment: @xiota - in theory  does, if the spec is fully implemented.  In practice that is not the case and absolutely should not be relied up on to work and failures may not be immediately apparent.

Comment: @scottbb There's a difference between creating a partition on a card and then later formatting that partition.

Comment: @MichaelClark absolutely. I'm willing to bet that if a camera formats a card, it will obliterate the partition table.

Comment: Good point.  FAT32 does technically support larger sizes, but there's a reason Windows (and most other formatters) limits it to 32 GB.  At larger sizes, the smallest representable file size gets larger, which means you end up wasting a lot of space storing small files.  To be fair, for photos, where sizes are in megabytes anyway, a 16 KB cluster size probably isn't a big deal.  On the other hand, you may not be able to actually mount such a volume on Windows, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @scottbb I've never tried it, but it seems to me that if the camera can only "see" the single partition, that's all it would format. It is certainly possible to format a single partition of a spinning hard disc. I don't see why it would not be the same for flash memory, but I guess it might.

Comment: The camera sees the partition table.  It could respect it, or it could nuke it and try to create a whole-device partition (or, for that matter, it could reformat it without a partition table at all, with a filesystem starting at block 0).  My guess is that it will respect it, because the latter would cause data loss if someone adds a second partition, which probably isn't what a user would normally expect.  But it really is anybody's guess.  :-)

Comment: @dgatwood I make the opposite assumption: say a camera sees a card with no partition table, or a corrupted table. It's going to blow it away, create its own, and format the partition. I've never seen a camera with any options when formatting to respect existing data, partitions, etc. You only get "Warning: all existing data will be lost by this operation". That's enough to assume away worries about data loss.  I assume cameras assume the card is theirs exclusively. Makes the software MUCH simpler, requiring much less testing to handle cases that are rare, by eliminating the rare cases.

Comment: ... I guess I should be more conservative with my assumptions. At least with Canon. [Michael's answer to an older question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/47585/11924) seems to indicate the partition information (for at least the active partition) is left alone with a normal format, but Canons also have a low-level format option.

Comment: No partition table or corrupted table, sure, but having a partition that does not fill the device != corrupted.  :-)